# java JTable ignores mouse event

Tags: java, swing, events, jtable

My problem is when I add a MouseListener to a JTable, there is no result.

Example:
The class OnlineList extends JTable.

```
// In constructor:
public OnlineList() {

    this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            System.out.println("Check mouse click");
        }
    });
}
```

There is no output like "Check mouse click"
I think the event listener is ignored.

Comment: who is `this`, are you sure `this` is a `Table` ?

Comment: Why not a `ListSelectionListener`?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to do what you want and all works properly. Here is my code:

```
    public static void main(String... s) {
     JFrame test = new JFrame("Test");
     JTable t = new JTable(new Object[][]{{1,2},{2,3}},new Object[]{"a","b"});
     t.addMouseListener(getMouseListener());
     test.add(new JScrollPane(t));
     test.setVisible(true);
     test.pack();
}

private static MouseListener getMouseListener() {
    return new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("test");
        }
    };
}
```

I recommend you to validate **this** object in your code, is it really your table?